# Acceleration vector as a function of Position vector?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, calculus

Details given in the question.

Initial Position vector was $(x_₀,y_₀)$
Initial Velocity vector $(v_ᵪ,v_ᵧ)$
Magnitude of acceleration - $a$(constant)

$x$ is position in horizontal direction

$y$ is position in vertical direction

Acceleration vector -$a \frac{x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}}{\sqrt{x^²+y^²}}$

How to find position vector as a function of time?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* tapus aggarwal! I've voted to close your question for the "Not suitable for this site" reason (*"Homework-like questions and check-my-work questions are considered off-topic here, particularly when asking about specific computations instead of underlying physics concepts"*).

Comment: This isn't a question that I received from school or anything I was animating sum stuff and wanted to describe a motion given above

Comment: do you think anybody is getting homework in this lockdown

Comment: Position, velocity, and acceleration are all interdependent and changing with time. I doubt that any formula can predict that motion. I would use a numeric simulation.

Comment: tapus, please *carefully* note that a question does not need to be *homework* to be considered *homework-like*. That is, it's irrelevant if the question comes from an actual homework assignment or not. You can edit your question to give the context and to show the research that you've already done. The question may then be reopened. You might find the following link helpful:  [How do I ask a good question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yeah that would be true if velocity vector would be perpendicular to acceleration vector

Comment: but here we have any arbitrary initial velocity vector

Comment: Yeah the magnitude is constant amd and direction is always pointing towards origin @AlfredCentauri

Comment: Now the question is how can I find position as a function of time we could use a = v dv/dx but acceleration depends on x and y both so how will i integrate @AlfredCentauri

Comment: But my real question is how to integrate two variables @AlfredCentauri